# How to get rid of this error in QTP?

Tags: testing, vbscript, automation, qtp

I am new to `QTP` and trying to resolve the error. I have used the dynamic method of Descriptive programming. When running the below code I get this error:

> "The "[ WebButton ]" object's description matches more than one of the
>   objects currently displayed in your application. Add additional
>   properties to the object description in order to uniquely identify the
>   object."

My script is:

```
Set oDesc=Description.Create()
oDesc("title").value="Google"
Set oDesc1=Description.Create()
oDesc1("name").value="q"
Set oDesc2=Description.Create()
oDesc2("html tag").value="INPUT"
oDesc2("height").value="30"
oDesc2("index:").value="0"

Browser(oDesc).page(oDesc).WebEdit(oDesc1).Set 10
Browser(oDesc).page(oDesc).WebButton(oDesc2).Click
```

I have used "index" property in order for `QTP` to uniquely identify the object. Please help.

Comment: can you try removing the colon ":" after the index property
make it oDesc2("index").value="0" and check

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
oDesc2("index").value="0"
```

instead of

```
oDesc2("index:").value="0"
```

You have included extra colon (**:**) in your property name. Object property name is "**index**" and you have given "**index:**"